# how is HTML newline rendered in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I have a `<textarea>` in which I enter multiple numbers, one on each line(by pressing enter to go to new line in the text area). I receive these numbers on my server side after form submission. Let's call the `<textarea>`'s input `'X'` . When I echo `'X'` to the browser, the numbers in '`X'` are separated by space. I know that `HTML` doesn't support `'\n'` character. But, on my server side, I want to use `explode()` function to get all numbers in `'X'` as separate elements of an array. Now, I am not able to find the delimiter which should be used in `explode()`. I tried using `'\n'` as delimiter but it doesn't separate the numbers after using `explode()`. Thus, I am not using the right delimiter. So, my question is **'what is the delimiter I should use and how is a HTML new line character(made by pressing enter in `<textarea>`) rendered in `PHP`?** Please remember my purpose is not echoing on browser, my purpose is to separate the numbers using `explode()`

Comment: You need [`nl2br()`](http://in3.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function in PHP.

Comment: @GhostGambler awesome man! send it as answer, i will accept it.

Comment: It's browser/OS based. Try `"\r\n"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use "\n" instead of '\n'. This is because only inside of " the special characters are converted to their real character codes. They stay as they are inside of ' though.

See the following example code:

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/plain');
$test = 'test\ntest';
echo $test;
/*
test\ntest
*/

$test = "test\ntest";
echo $test;
/*
test
test
/*
```

Comment: You might want to cast `trim` on all exploded values. There might be some rest-whitespace left (like `\r` mentioned above, or just spaces or tabs). `array_walk($exploded, "trim")` does that job.